# How can I construct plural forms of words using Perl's ternary conditional operator?

Tags: perl, if-statement, nlp, conditional-operator

I am having some trouble making statements involving chained ternary conditional operators.

Obviously I can write them the standard way, but it would be useful to know why they aren't working properly.

Pseudo code for what I want to do:

> if $feature ends with 's', make $group = upper case $feature
>
> if $feature ends with 'y', remove the y & replace with 'ies' before making $group = upper case $feature
>
> if $feature ends with anything else, add an 's' and make $group = upper case $feature.

I have tried using c-style ifs:

```
substr($feature,-1) eq 'y' ? $group = uc(chop($feature)).'IES'
                           : substr($feature,-1) ne 's' ? $group = uc($feature).'S'
                                                        : $group = uc($feature);
```

and

```
substr($feature,-1) ne 's' ? substr($feature,-1) eq 'y' ? $group = uc(chop($feature)).'IES'
                                                        : $group = uc($feature).'S'
                           : $group = uc($feature);
```

What happens is that if I have a string in $feature that ends with say `e` or `n`, it doesn't find `$group = uc($feature).'S'`. I tried changing it around and using `eq 's'` but then it adds an extra `S` onto strings that already end with `s`.

Any help appreciated!

EDIT:

Here is what works thanks to `dan1111`:

```
$group = substr($feature,-1) ne 's' ? substr($feature,-1) eq 'y' ? uc(chop($feature)).'IES'
                                    : uc($feature).'S'
         : uc($feature);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quirk of Perl is that you can actually assign to the ternary operator:

```
condition ? $a : $b = 2;
```

This assigns `2` to either `$a` or `$b` depending on whether condition is true.

Similarly, in your code `uc($feature)` is being assigned to a different part of the conditional depending on what is true.

As a result, if `substr($feature,-1) ne 's'` is true in your code, Perl does something like this:

```
($group = uc($feature).'S') = uc($feature);
```

Which assigns `uc($feature)` to `$group`.

I think this feature of Perl is silly and somewhat regrettable.  Nonetheless, you really shouldn't be using the ternary operator for control flow.  Only use it for simple checks:

```
print $result == 1 ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

You certainly shouldn't combine multiple ternary operators together, because it is very confusing.  What is wrong with this?

```
if (substr($feature,-1) eq 'y')
{
    $group = uc(chop($feature)).'IES';
}
elsif (substr($feature,-1) ne 's')
{
    $group = uc($feature).'S';
}
else
{
    $group = uc($feature);
}
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the full ifs, I just wanted to know why the conditional ones didn't work when they should in theory. :)

Comment: @bladepanthera, fair enough.  Of course, if someone held a gun to your head and forced you to use the ternary operators, you could get them to work with parentheses.

Comment: true, but why make life simple? and now I (well, you) have cured an itch.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution to your immediate problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

say make_group($_) for qw( curly status color );

=for specification

if $feature ends with 's', make $group = upper case $feature

if $feature ends with 'y', remove the y & replace with 'ies' before making $group = upper case $feature

if $feature ends with anything else, add an 's' and make $group = upper case $feature.

=cut

sub make_group {
    my ($feature) = @_;
    my $last = substr($feature, -1);

    my $group = $last eq 's' ? uc($feature)
              : $last eq 'y' ? do { chop($feature); uc("${feature}ies") }
              : uc("${feature}s")
    ;

    return $group;
}

__END__
```

However, I would use [Lingua::EN::Inflect](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Lingua%3a%3aEN%3a%3aInflect):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';
use Lingua::EN::Inflect 'PL_N';

say uc(PL_N $_) for qw( curly status color );

__END__
```

Comment: +1 for interesting alternative. Never heard of 'Lingua::EN::Inflect'. Research time! The only thing I would say about it is that it is not immediately obvious what it does. `PL_N` is fairly ambiguous uncommented.

Comment: Well, not knowing about and using `Lingua::EN::Inflect` is your loss, especially given the number of exceptions it takes care of (say, *leaf*). `PL_N` stands for *plural noun*. Nothing is preventing you from using a more verbose alias.

Comment: Well, I know about it now! A quick check of the CPAN library solved that problem. Only reason I'm not using is because I have less than 10 words to check, so not much point really. Always happy to learn new ways to solve a problem, though, as it may well help me in the future.